# Tile layout for Mobile view(html,css) similar like hike messenger (coupons page)

Tags: html, css, layout, tile

[image: This is the image of layout in which i need your help please view it and help me]

I am having problem with creating simple HTML layout which looks exactly like copouns page in hike messenger. Please help me to figure it out.

Comment: Post all the code that you have tried. Ctrl + M opens a box for you to paste your code into

Comment: I have tried simple HTML code for that.but i am not able to make it.please help.

Comment: I'm saying post the code that you have tried